# Store and retrieve user js file from mysql. php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Is there any way to store a js file in mysql and then by using a php script retrieve it and include to website page?

Comment: Try asking a few smaller questions. I don't want to risk typing for half an hour to answer a user with no history.

Comment: you want the path to the js file or the whole script in db? explain why you want to do this..

Comment: Better yet: [How to store and retrieve text data in MySQL preserving the line breaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738690/how-to-store-and-retrieve-text-data-in-mysql-preserving-the-line-breaks) for PDO usage, just without the `nl2br` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsserver.php?id=1"/>
```

The jsserver.php script:

```
<?php
  // connect to your db the way you like

  $id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);
  $query='SELECT jsscript FROM jstable WHERE id='.$id;

  // execute query 

  // fetch javascript code from table "jstable" field "jsscript"

  // $jsscript contains the javascript code

  header('Content-type: text/javascript');  
  echo $jsscript;

?>
```

This should be enough for you the get the job done.